# How to send custom HTTP header in response?

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-headers, phpwebsocket

I want to send json data in my HTTP Header.

I am using Codeigniter PHP, so I did this in my controller:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');'
```

This is my code:

```
$request = array(

    'request' => $_GET['request'],
    'device_id' => $_GET['device_id'],
    'launch_date'=> $_GET['launch_date'],
    'allowed_hours'=>$_GET['allowed_hours'],
    'site_id'=>$_GET['site_id'],
    'product'=>$_GET['product'],
    'software_version'=>$_GET['software_version'],
    'platform_os'=>$_GET['platform_os'],
    'platform'=>$_GET['platform'],
    'platform_model'=>$_GET['platform_model']

     );
$response = array(
    'response_code' =>200 ,
    'device_id'=>$_GET['device_id'],
    'allowed_hours'=>$_GET['allowed_hours'],
    'product'=>'mlc',
    'prov_ur'=>NULL 
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $response );
```

But when I print my header I get

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message:  Undefined index: request
>
> Filename: admin/license.php
>
> Line Number: 22
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message:  Undefined index:
>   allowed_hours
>
> Filename: admin/license.php
>
> Line Number:
>   25
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message:  Undefined index:
>   allowed_hours
>
> Filename: admin/license.php
>
> Line Number:
>   40
>
> {"response_code":200,"device_id":"70D0D01FBAD2","allowed_hours":null,"product":"mlc","prov_ur":null}array(10)
>   {   ["Host"]=>   string(14) "192.168.50.123"   ["Connection"]=>
>   string(10) "keep-alive"   ["Cache-Control"]=>   string(9) "max-age=0" 
>   ["Accept"]=>   string(74)
>   "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
>   ["Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"]=>   string(1) "1"   ["User-Agent"]=>
>   string(110) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
>   ["Accept-Encoding"]=>   string(19) "gzip, deflate, sdch"
>   ["Accept-Language"]=>   string(14) "en-US,en;q=0.8"   ["Cookie"]=>
>   string(518)
>   "cisession=OhhBBhVodwwf7Tb55AVsU32ClMS5cgmxBl15WHA%2BrGnvo1kiK%2B67BWeAuJVSV2MY25zZd0riHC9cyx9fiigiBuqkPMT%2FKE9d6et%2FXaE3F7I59P9%2FEzy5byQ5nEkJq5xwXoH1I7%2B7v62cQL21%2Bjfnk3AwIy4luM7N51IUuTqg7TxunoZFD1gJO84r8degY1imNpmDk2W%2FjsQPn9bQpkWJ9KVMxxViFDaELEU0rIfYmif%2BdvXjK9W%2Fj7iWQxZYE9ZGazgBTKlLO%2BJZHNdPrdmGPFTzTUROZdffpF%2Bb25bRMPEJsZ9CE2mdVuSn%2FEu678utd0lcd9bh%2BDbTDikrHP4jBFOLbZfWKT%2F9r5GkMBrLBl%2BlvPx9RbAq%2FIsjeA1V7c6JYf41TO1bG2XKT14QFHm8m0qY8HCal%2B%2BR8tZe9i3zy24%3Dcfc459942e4ef82a5554257216a19d621f446a25"
>   ["If-Modified-Since"]=>   string(29) "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" }

```
{"response_code":200,"device_id":"70D0D01FBAD2","allowed_hours":null,"product":"mlc","prov_ur":null}
```

in my response. I don't want to send other data in my HTTP header response.

**Upadted Code as per CI**

```
public function index()
{
    $request = array(
        'request' => $this->get('request'),
        'device_id' => $this->get('device_id'),
        'launch_date'=> $this->get('launch_date'),
        'allowed_hours'=>$this->get('allowed_hours'),
        'site_id'=> $this->get('site_id'),
        'product'=>$this->get('product'),
        'software_version'=> $this->get('software_version'),
        'platform_os'=> $this->get('platform_os'),
        'platform'=> $this->get('platform'),
        'platform_model'=> $this->get('platform_model')
    );

    $response = array(
        'response_code' =>200 ,
        'device_id'=> $this->get('device_id'),
        'allowed_hours'=> $this->get('allowed_hours'),
        'product'=>'mlc',
        'prov_ur'=>NULL 
    );

    $this->output->set_content_type('Content-Type: application/json');

    return $this->output
    ->set_content_type('Content-Type: application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode($response));

    echo $response;

}
```

Comment: the error explains the problem - there are missing GET variables - make sure you set them before sending the response

Comment: @RamRaider i  have set my GET variables in array $request

Comment: `Message: Undefined index: allowed_hours` this line suggested that you need to set first : `'allowed_hours'`

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd Thanks for drawing my attenetion

Comment: Thanks @RamRaider i got it

Comment: you have doubled up on set_content_type

Comment: Try and just have the return code comment out the echo and give it ago

Comment: Not yet working i removed the  set_content _type but still a blank screen ! it this an error?

Comment: In here $this->get your missing input should be $this->input->get

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Yeah got it thanks buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the normal php get like below will sometimes throw some errors

```
$_GET['allowed_hours'];
```

I would recommend change to codeIgniter input class methods.

```
$this->input->get('allowed_hours');
```

Codeigniter [Input Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#accessing-form-data) will save you putting lot of code.

As said in user guide: With CodeIgniter’s built in methods you can simply do this:

**Updated:**

```
$request = array(
   'request' => $this->input->get('request'),
   'device_id' => $this->input->get('device_id'),
   'launch_date'=> $this->input->get('launch_date'),
   'allowed_hours'=> $this->input->get('allowed_hours'),
   'site_id'=> $this->input->get('site_id'),
   'product'=>$this->input->get('product'),
   'software_version'=> $this->input->get('software_version'),
   'platform_os'=> $this->input->get('platform_os'),
   'platform'=> $this->input->get('platform'),
   'platform_model'=> $this->input->get('platform_model')
);
```

Codeigniter has own [Output Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html?#CI_Output::set_content_type)

And

```
$response = array(
    'response_code' => 200,
    'device_id'=> $this->input->get('device_id'),
    'allowed_hours'=> $this->input->get('allowed_hours'),
    'product'=> 'mlc',
    'prov_ur'=> NULL 
);

return $this->output
      ->set_content_type('Content-Type: application/json')
      ->set_output(json_encode($response));
```

Comment: i am updating my code please check i am not gettin proper response

Comment: You for got the set_output();

Comment: added this after my code: echo $this->output->set_output(json_encode($response));

Comment: i should be getting the JSON data echoed on screen

Comment: updated my question code please check the screen show white blank screen

Comment: You have your $this->get() wrong.Should be $this->input->get() Did it work now

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that some of your `$_GET` variables aren't set, this will throw an error (the extra output text you have) and can be prevent by checking if they are empty first before using them.

```
$request = array(
    'request' => !empty($_GET['request']) ? $_GET['request'] : '',
    'device_id' => !empty($_GET['device_id']) ? $_GET['device_id'] : '',
    'launch_date'=> !empty($_GET['launch_date']) ? $_GET['launch_date'] : '',
    'allowed_hours'=> !empty($_GET['allowed_hours']) ? $_GET['allowed_hours'] : '',
    'site_id'=> !empty($_GET['site_id']) ? $_GET['site_id'] : '',
    'product'=> !empty($_GET['product']) ? $_GET['product'] : '',
    'software_version'=> !empty($_GET['software_version']) ? $_GET['software_version'] : '',
    'platform_os'=> !empty($_GET['platform_os']) ? $_GET['platform_os'] : '',
    'platform'=> !empty($_GET['platform']) ? $_GET['platform'] : '',
    'platform_model'=> !empty($_GET['platform_model']) ? $_GET['platform_model'] : ''
);

$response = array(
    'response_code' =>200 ,
    'device_id'=> !empty($_GET['device_id']) ? $_GET['device_id'] : '',
    'allowed_hours'=> !empty($_GET['allowed_hours']) ? $_GET['allowed_hours'] : '',
    'product'=>'mlc',
    'prov_ur'=>NULL 
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $response );
```

Comment: Codeigniter input class method's are a lot easier and less code.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I know, I never said this was the best solution. This is just one of the many possible solutions ;)